# Folders become unknown, undeleteable file type. How to fix and/or delete?

Tags: external-sd

I'm trying to re-organize and replace the music on my phone's ext. SD card, but some of the folders have become some sort of unknown file type. In Windows, the properties window just says it's file type is "File". That's it.

I can't delete, open, or move them (from my PC or in the phone itself); however, I can still listen to the music (only through my music player app) and rename the folders. I've tried deleting them in Windows, in my phone's music player app, and in my phone's file manager but nothing seems to work; on Windows it says,

> [Album name] could not be deleted. The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected.

and on my phone deleting it does nothing and gives no feedback whatsoever.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm okay with deleting the files since I have more copies, but that doesn't seem to be possible either. I would probably be okay with most options except nuking the entire SD card

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should reboot your phone. Android re-scans the sd-card after the reboot. Hopefully this fixes the consistency issues you see.

Comment: @Robert I've rebooted multiple times and they're still like that. One day they were normal folders, and now they're just "Files" — it doesn't switch between or anything. So I don't think this is a consistency issue; they changed, but they're not changing back on their own.